# Deploying app to Heroku, ENV variables not wokring

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, mongoose

I have recently deployed my node js app to Heroku and am having some trouble getting my app to work.  My app loads but when i try to sign in it breaks.  As far as I can tell is the environment variable are not loading correctly for some reason.  The db variable is a string taken from my .ENV file and is the Monogo URI used to connect to mongo db.  For some reason when heroku runs it process.env.MongoURI is coming undefined.  Does anybody know why this might be happening?

The specific error I am getting is.

### Error

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

### App.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable arrow-parens */
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const indexRouter = require('./server/index');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

require('./server/config/passport')(passport);

// DB Config
const db = process.env.MongoURI;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }) // I beleieve this is the line that is breaking the code.
  .then(() => { console.log('MONGODB Connected'); })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably should use Heroku's built in environment variable editor for this purpose.

Comment: Yes! It' the same for Vercel and other hosting services. Even though there is the `.env`, we have to configure the environment variables in their built in env editor.

Comment: @AjitKumar I just learned about the built in config variables in the Heroku Dashboard, basically I just need to place all my .env variables over there then I can reference them in code how I am using with dotenv.  It seems a bit insecure for me to have my private variables in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your `.env` is added to your  `.gitignore` file. When you deploy your project to heroku, it will automatically adapt to the variables on its new host. 
Find more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#be-environmentally-aware

Comment: Thats what I saw in the docs as well before I deployed and that's the behavior I was expecting.  My gitignore already include my env file.